# Python interface pattern and unit test code coverage

Tags: python, unit-testing, code-coverage, python-unittest

I'm working in a python project using `unittest` for testing along with `coverage` for code coverage.
I use the interface pattern extensively and I noticed that the overall code coverage percentage is heavily influenced by "non tested interfaces".
Consider the following:

```
class IReader(object):
    @abstractmethod
    def read(self):
        pass


class Reader(IReader):
    def read(self):
        # whatever
```

I test `Reader` but (obviously) I do not test `IReader` so
the `pass` instruction is  marked as not covered by tests.

Is there a way to ignore the interfaces from `coverage`? 
Since this is one of my first python project, am I doing this totally wrong?

Comment: Add `#pragma: no cover` comment inline. Or maybe `raise NotImplementedError` (although I'm not sure if it'll be excluded by default from coverage).

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski I don't think it does but you can configure coverage to do so. See [the docs](http://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.3.4/excluding.html#advanced-exclusion) and my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't really see the point of having this `read` method defined with pass as single instruction. If you don't need it, let it raise `NotImplementedError`.

```
class IReader(object):
    @abstractmethod
    def read(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

As specified in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod), an abstract method can have an implementation used by children with `super()`. But in your case, it does nothing. Therefore, unless you have a good reason, you might as well let it raise `NotImplementedError`.

(Arguably, a good reason could be a pattern where all your children call `super().my_method()` for some reason, so you need an implementation for all methods in the abstract class.)

#### How to exclude the abstract method from coverage report

Regardless, the test coverage is just an indicator you build: the part of the code you want to test that you actually test. Defining the "code you want to test" is up to you.

You could add a test to check that the abstract method returns `NotImplementedError` or just `pass`es, if you see an interest in this.

Or you may think (which seems reasonable) that testing this is pointless, in which case [excluding](http://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.3.4/excluding.html) the method from coverage report `#pragma: no cover` seems like the way to go:

```
class IReader(object):  #pragma: no cover
    @abstractmethod
    def read(self):
        pass
```

The doc page linked above shows how you can also exclude all `NotImplementedError` methods adding this to your configuration file:

```
[report]
exclude_lines =
    pragma: no cover
    raise NotImplementedError
```

so that you don't have to add a `pragma` to each abstract method.

---

### **2020 edit**

I just noticed the @abstractmethod decorator. Since it prevents the class from being instantiated, I wouldn't raise `NotImplementedError`. See [this other answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44315961/when-to-use-raise-notimplementederror/44316506#44316506)

I'd just leave the method empty. Syntaxically, a docstring is enough

```
class IReader(object):
    @abstractmethod
    def read(self):
        """Read data"""
```