# When to use 'raise NotImplementedError'?

Tags: python, oop

Is it to remind yourself and your team to implement the class correctly?
I don't fully get the use of an abstract class like this:

```
class RectangularRoom(object):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def cleanTileAtPosition(self, pos):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def isTileCleaned(self, m, n):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Comment: Cross-site dupe: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/231397/110531

Comment: I would say: When it satisfies the ["Principle of least astonishment"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Comment: This is a useful question, as evidenced by the clear answer by Uriel as per the docs, and the value-add answer regarding abstract base classes by Jérôme .

Comment: It can also be used to to indicate that a derived class purposely does not implement a base class abstract method, which can offer a two-way protection. [See below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61800126/6118556).

Comment: ... every time when you do have not enough developer resources

Comment: In any case, raise an instance (`NotImplementedError()`), not the class itself (`NotImplementedError`).

Answer (score 140):

As the documentation states [<sup>[docs]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#NotImplementedError),

> In user defined base classes, abstract methods should raise this exception when they require derived classes to override the method, or while the class is being developed to indicate that the real implementation still needs to be added.

Note that although the main stated use case this error is the indication of abstract methods that should be implemented on inherited classes, you can use it anyhow you'd like, like for indication of a `TODO` marker.

Comment: For abstract methods, I prefer to use `abc` (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44316506/4653485)).

Comment: @Jérôme why not use both? Decorate with `abstractmethod` and let it raise `NotImplementedError`. This prohibits `super().method()` in implementations of `method` in derived classes.

Comment: @timgeg I don't feel the need to prohibit super().method().

Comment: Would argue with the need of ABC. When you create a class instantiated from ABC with abstractmethods all around you make it difficult to test specific methods (or use one method) in your tests. It is OK at the beginning but later on you would find yourself implementing all the methods that are marked as abstractmethods just to use one method from your class in some tests.

Answer (score 82):

As [Uriel says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44316063/4653485), it is meant for a method in an abstract class that should be implemented in child class, but can be used to indicate a TODO as well.

There is an alternative for the first use case: [Abstract Base Classes](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/abc.html). Those help creating abstract classes.

Here's a Python 3 example:

```
class C(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def my_abstract_method(self, ...):
        ...
```

When instantiating `C`, you'll get an error because `my_abstract_method` is abstract. You need to implement it in a child class.

```
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class C with abstract methods my_abstract_method
```

Subclass `C` and implement `my_abstract_method`.

```
class D(C):
    def my_abstract_method(self, ...):
        ...
```

Now you can instantiate `D`.

`C.my_abstract_method` does not have to be empty. It can be called from `D` using `super()`.

An advantage of this over `NotImplementedError` is that you get an explicit `Exception` at instantiation time, not at method call time.

Comment: Available in Python 2.6+ as well. Just `from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod` and define your ABC with `__metaclass__ = ABCMeta`. Docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html

Comment: If you want to use this with a class that defines a metaclass, you need to create a new metaclass that inherits both the original metaclass of the class and ABCMeta.

Answer (score 38):

Consider if instead it was:

```
class RectangularRoom(object):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        pass

    def cleanTileAtPosition(self, pos):
        pass

    def isTileCleaned(self, m, n):
        pass
```

and you subclass and forget to tell it how to `isTileCleaned()` or, perhaps more likely, typo it as `isTileCLeaned()`. Then in your code, you'll get a `None` when you call it.

- Will you get the overridden function you wanted? Definitely not.
- Is `None` valid output? Who knows.
- Is that intended behavior? Almost certainly not.
- Will you get an error? It depends.

`raise NotImplmentedError` *forces* you to implement it, as it **will** throw an exception when you try to run it until you do so. This removes a lot of silent errors. It's similar to why a [bare except is almost never a good idea](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html#except): because people make mistakes and this makes sure they aren't swept under the rug.

Note: Using an abstract base class, as other answers have mentioned, is better still, as then the errors are frontloaded and the program won't run until you implement them (with NotImplementedError, it will only throw an exception if actually called).

Answer (score 32):

One could also do a `raise NotImplementedError()` *inside* the child method of an  `@abstractmethod`-decorated base class method. – Yes, it's a mouthful but what it **really means** is **graceful simplicity**.

---

## Example

Imagine writing a control script for a family of electronic measurement modules (i.e. physical devices).
The functionality of each module is narrowly-defined, implementing just one dedicated function:
one could be an array of relays, another a multi-channel DAC or ADC, another an ammeter etc.

Many of the low-level commands would be shared between the modules for example to read
their ID numbers or to send a command to them. Let's see what we have at this point:

### Base Class

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod  #< we'll make use of these later

class Generic(ABC):
    ''' Base class for all measurement modules. '''

    # Shared functions
    def __init__(self):
        # do what you must...

    def _read_ID(self):
        # same for all the modules

    def _send_command(self, value):
        # same for all the modules
```

---

#### Shared Verbs

We then realise that much of the module-specific command verbs and, therefore, the
logic of their interfaces is also shared. Here are 3 different verbs whose meaning
would be self-explanatory considering a number of target modules.

**`get(channel)`:**

- **relay:** get the on/off status of the relay on `channel`
- **DAC:** get the *output* voltage on `channel`
- **ADC:** get the *input* voltage on `channel`

**`enable(channel)`:**

- **relay:** enable the use of the relay on `channel`
- **DAC:** enable the use of the *output* channel on `channel`
- **ADC:** enable the use of the *input* channel on `channel`

**`set(channel)`:**

- **relay:** set the relay on `channel` on/off
- **DAC:** set the *output* voltage on `channel`
- **ADC:** hmm... nothing *logical* comes to mind.

---

#### Shared Verbs Become Enforced Verbs

I'd argue that there is a strong case for the above verbs to be shared across the modules
as we saw that their meaning is evident for each one of them. I'd continue writing my
base class `Generic` like so:

```
class Generic(ABC):  # ...continued
    
    @abstractmethod
    def get(self, channel):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def enable(self, channel):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def set(self, channel):
        pass
```

---

### Subclasses

We now know that our subclasses will all have to define these methods. Let's see what it
could look like for the ADC module:

```
class ADC(Generic):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  #< applies to all modules
        # more init code specific to the ADC module
    
    def get(self, channel):
        # returns the input value measured on the given 'channel'

    def enable(self, channel):
        # enables accessing the given 'channel'
```

You may now be wondering:

> But this won't work for the **ADC** module as **`set`** makes no sense there!

You're right: NOT implementing `set` is not an option as Python would then fire the error below at you
as soon as your as you tried instantiating your ADC object.

```
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class 'ADC' with abstract methods 'set'
```

So you must implement `set`, because we made it an *enforced verb* (aka `@abstractmethod`),
which is shared by two other modules. But, what should you implement if `set` does not make sense for this particular module? What makes the interface (for users) and the code-base (for future maintenance) as clean as possible?

### NotImplementedError to the Rescue

By completing the ADC class like this:

```
class ADC(Generic): # ...continued

    def set(self, channel):
        raise NotImplementedError("Can't use 'set' on an ADC!")
```

You are doing three very good things at once:

1. You are protecting a user from erroneously issuing a command ('set') that is
   not (and shouldn't!) be implemented for this module.
2. You are telling them **explicitly** what the problem is (see TemporalWolf's link about
   'Bare exceptions' for why this is important)
3. You are protecting the implementation of all the other modules for which the *enforced verbs*
   do make sense. I.e. you ensure that those modules for which these verbs *do* make sense will
   implement these methods and that **they will do so using exactly these verbs** and not some
   other ad-hoc names.

Answer (score -4):

You might want to you use the `@property` decorator,

```
>>> class Foo():
...     @property
...     def todo(self):
...             raise NotImplementedError("To be implemented")
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.todo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in todo
NotImplementedError: To be implemented
```

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the question, which is *when to use it*.