# Confused about function

Tags: python, function, pycharm

I'm in the beginning of making a function and this is my code right now:

```
def shortest_path(source, target):

    frontier_d = {}

    frontier_d[source]=1


    raise NotImplementedError
```

Basically, I'm trying to make a dictionary and put source, the input of the function, as a key associated with the value 1. However, Pycharm is telling me that source is an unsolved reference. Why is this occurring if source is an input to the function?

Comment: A screenshot or full output of the error would be nice

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You haven't shown where you call the function and the problem could be there. Can you add an extra line to call `shortest_path` and include any traceback you get when running it? Also, raising is going to confuse matters for this test. Best to take it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this-
[When to use 'raise NotImplementedError'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44315961/when-to-use-raise-notimplementederror)

```
source="abc"
target=156
def shortest_path(source, target):
    try:
        frontier_d = {}
        frontier_d[source]=target
        print(frontier_d)
    except:
        raise NotImplementedError
shortest_path(source, target)
```

output: {'abc': 156}